# How can I cycle a USB device from C#?

Tags: c#, api, stack, usb, peripherals

I'd like to cycle (simulate unplug and re-inserting) a USB device (modem) after a certain event has fired. I found a sample on codeproject:

> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/usbeject.aspx

That allows me to identify+eject the device via its non-volatile serial, but I need it to recycle, not just eject.

I have read this:

> http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.development.device.drivers/2005-02/1292.html

I do not understand it.

This has been mentioned in other USB related posts:

> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/DriveDetector.aspx

It is not relevant to my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by recycle? Do you mean a soft reboot? Or do you mean "move it to the recycle bin"?

Comment: reboot, same as removing the device and re-inserting it.

Comment: See my answer to this problem below

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Got it working by using a commandline tool called devcon, which I then called from code.

Dropped devcon.exe into one of the system paths so it works everywhere.

Devcon: [devcon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272)

called: DEVCON Remove *usb"*MI_01"

then called: DEVCON rescan

code:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
 proc.StartInfo.FileName = "DEVCON";
 proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "Remove *usb"*MI_01";
 proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
 proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 proc.Start();
```

Comment: It would be good if you could add a link to devcon and some example code so other people can learn.

Comment: I had a device (touchscreen controller) that I did something similar with, but I actually had to remove/rescan on the HUB for it to work.  It may have been a crappy hub, 9and it was definitely a crappy driver) but the remove on the device still left it powered, and removing the hub actually cut the power.

Comment: I tried devcon, but I always get "access is denied" when using it from the command line. Win 7 pro. Any ideas why?

Comment: On Windows 7 you need to be Administrator to run certain devcon commands.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [C# Hardware Helper Lib](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21503/Hardware-Helper-Library-for-C) and add the [ResetDevice function](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21503/Hardware-Helper-Library-for-C?msg=4467165#xx4467165xx).

Just make sure you add

```
public const int DICS_PROPCHANGE = ((0x00000003));
```

at the `public class Native` under //PARMS,

```
public bool ResetDevice( IntPtr hDevInfo, IntPtr devInfoData )
{
int szOfPcp;
IntPtr ptrToPcp;
int szDevInfoData;
IntPtr ptrToDevInfoData;

Native.SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS pcp = new Native.SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS();
pcp.ClassInstallHeader.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Native.SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER));
pcp.ClassInstallHeader.InstallFunction = Native.DIF_PROPERTYCHANGE;
pcp.StateChange = Native.DICS_PROPCHANGE; // for reset
pcp.Scope = Native.DICS_FLAG_CONFIGSPECIFIC;
pcp.HwProfile = 0;

szOfPcp = Marshal.SizeOf(pcp);
ptrToPcp = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(szOfPcp);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(pcp, ptrToPcp, true);
szDevInfoData = Marshal.SizeOf(devInfoData);
ptrToDevInfoData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(szDevInfoData);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(devInfoData, ptrToDevInfoData, true);

bool rslt1 = Native.SetupDiSetClassInstallParams(hDevInfo, ptrToDevInfoData, ptrToPcp, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Native.SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS)));
bool rstl2 = Native.SetupDiCallClassInstaller(Native.DIF_PROPERTYCHANGE, hDevInfo, ptrToDevInfoData);

if (rslt1 && rstl2)
{
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```