# How to issue USB device reconnection under Windows

Tags: usb, deadlock, device-driver, ftdi

I have an USB device based on FTDI chip. Sometimes, its driver get stuck.

Under linux, there no problem -- device get automatically disconnected, and reconnected by default kernel, and only problem is device name changed -- that can be fixed by udev rules.

Under windows, when it stuck, application's thread that does `read()` or `write()` at that moment are completely hangs. It can't be killed nor by `TerminateThread`, nor by `KillProcess`.

The only way to kill app -- is disconnect USB device physically.

Any way to issue programmatically device reconnection, that will remove driver's deadlock and allow to re-open port and continue working after?

Administrative rights application can have, if that required.

Comment: "devcon.exe restart * ftdi *"
"devcon.exe disable * ftdi *"
are fails while in hung state

Comment: The bad news is that the FTDI-based devices are the most reliable ones on the market! - devices based on the PL2303 (and/or their chipset vendor's drivers) are severely broken.

Comment: Did you try a newer driver from [ftdichip.com](http://ftdichip.com)?

Comment: Always using latest driver. And tried to contact with support of ftdi without luck. Currently, only alarming of user to "please reconnect device" possible, trying to find another solutions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916296/how-can-i-cycle-a-usb-device-from-c/919836#919836

Comment: devcon didn't work, so emulation of it didn't work either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest that you move your thinking up a step. You are trying to restart the USB device directly, why not try the hub?

I had a similar problem, and doing:

```
devcon remove *ROOT_HUB* && devcon rescan
```

Re-attached the USB device to the hub when it was hung.

**Note**: This will remove ALL USB devices from the device manager and re-add them. You can use expect or alike to do `devcon findall *ROOT_HUB*` and remove either `ROOT_HUB20` or `ROOT_HUB30` as needed.

Comment: it seems to fails for me to shutdown hub, like device itself... :/

Comment: Sounds like your problem may not be with the device, but your USB hub. Do you have another computer or USB hub you can try it on?

Comment: it's mb onboard usb hub, i'll check with external passive and active usb hub, thanks for suggestion! that seems to be real solution

Comment: additional info: under win8 its stable re-connects after that stuck by itself. under win7 it working to disable root hub on some mb