# How to restart an USB with a powershell script/batch file?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

Ok, here's my problem: The place I work for uses [these devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJIyf.png) as an authentication method. The little monsters tend to fail constantly and the only way to make them work again is by restarting the PC. Since restarting a PC takes a long time (we take time seriously) I want to know if there's an alternative by using powershell or a batch file to automate the task.

OS: 7, 8, 8.1

Thanks!

Edit: I've used DevCon, but I need a script or something that requires NO extra software.

I just used devcon and this happend: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l3FT.png). The device is connected.

Comment: Have you tried unplugging/pluggin the device? If it works, maybe an automated solution is possible.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, it works when I unplug/plug the device (: I just need the script as a fast way of response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I cycle a USB device from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916296/how-can-i-cycle-a-usb-device-from-c)

Comment: Try [Reset method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393077) of the CIM_Controller class.  Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/38021644/4317867